# C# SortedSet introduces null object

Tags: c#, .net, null, sortedset

I am using a `SortedSet` that is instantiated as

```
new SortedSet<myClass>(IEnumerable<myClass>, new MyCustomComparer())
```

The problem I'm having is that although there are no `null` objects in `IEnumerable` before creating the `SortedSet`, one exists in the set once it is created. The only way I've been able to track this is by looking at the comparer and conclude that sometimes one of the inputs is `null`. However, when or how the `null` is introduced is a mystery.

I know this is probably difficult to answer without having all the specifics at hand, but are there any circumstances which could lead to an object in the input collection to be set to `null` during the `SortedSet` initialization?

Thanks

EDIT: I had some copy paste errors in the code. Updated those

Comment: you should provide reproducible code

Comment: @LeiYang I would have if I could figure out the parameters that cause the problem. As it stands I do not know why this is happening and thus cannot reproduce it outside of the project I'm working in.

Comment: It is **much** more likely that there is a null value in your enumerable, rather than the SortedSet somehow adding that value by itself

Comment: Is it possible that your enumerable contains objects of a type that cannot be automatically casted to IShape2DParticle? Those might be leading to null values in your SortedSet.

Comment: @MichaelWürthner I had made an error in the example. Sorry. I do a prior step where I use OfType to only select the objects of type `myClass`. So there should not be any casting involved.

@KevinGosse I agree! But when I break in the debugger there are no null objects prior to the initialization of the `SortedSet`. Could VS somehow be tricking me?

Comment: Try initializing it without `MyCustomComparer` to see if that is the problem.

Comment: @Magnus A good suggestion. I was able to ascertain that it always was the first item in the list to be sorted that was being nulled so it wasn't comparer specific. I've scrapped using SortedSet and moved to OrderBy since there is only a single sort required.

Comment: I see the same behvaiour in my code several times. No null elements in input collection, but null as a compared object in Compare method of custom comparer. And can not find out how it can be at source code https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/generic/sortedset.cs